# Enterprise Keywords textbox on a page

Tags: 2013, development, enterprise-keywords, inputformtextbox

I have a question regarding the Enterprise Keywords Textbox. Normally, if Enterprise Keywords are active you can add keywords on new form or edit form, there, when you type they are automatically separated by a ";" and are underscored.

Now I want to have the same behavior but on my custom page... so how can I do this programmatically? Which type of textbox should I add to make sure that the same behavior occurs there as it does in the default for "Enterprise Keywords"?